# Java update while system is running

Tags: java

So I am programming in java, I need to know if there is a way to update code while it's running, so say I am running the code GUI, and when I change the code while it's running it changes and I can click it again to fix the code. How would I do this? Is it a plugin or some package?

Comment: Not very easily, no.

Comment: Hot swapping is a complicated process, which doesn't always work.  A better solution would be to "detect" the change and then restart the App with the new code - "how" is greatly depended on your current structure

Comment: Are you asking how you, the developer, can hot swap code while debugging? That depends on what debugger you're using, but it's a fairly common feature these days. But if you're asking how to *implement* hot swapping in your own program (not using the debugger) then that's well beyond a "beginner" level project.